# How to instance messageSource in a service

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I am using grails 2 and I am trying to calls service that calls a MessageSource but is always null. Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this and it work for me:

```
def messageSource
```

And you have to use it like this:

```
messageSource.getMessage('enrolment.state.registered', null, Locale.default)
```

I hope it help.

Comment: Don't answer duplicate questions. This already has already been asked before, and answered quite well. Answering duplicate questions makes SO less useful to the community at large.